# How to add code into a page with a lot of conflicting CSS, without using Scoped CSS?

Tags: html, css, merge

i'm trying to add code for tabs into a page which already loads a lot of conflicting CSS. I've tried editing the names of div classes and labels, but the original still fights with the code i'm adding. Scoped CSS would be the perfect solution, except it isn't widely supported yet.

What other options do i have?

Here's a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dcLjve28/1/
Here's the page i want to add it into to organise the boxes better: http://action.focallocal.org/

i won't include the CSS already being loaded on the page as it's a huge amount of code (unless someone asks), but i'll post the code i want to add into it here for anyone who'd prefer that to JS Fiddle:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content1 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked >
    <label for="tab1">
       <i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>Projects</span>
    </label>
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content2 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
    <label for="tab2">
        <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Flash-Mobs</span>
    </label>
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content3 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
    <label for="tab3">
       <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Movement</span>
    </label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Positive Action Projects</h3>
        <p><!-- Tab content here --></p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content1 -->
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Internatonal Positive Action Days</h3>
        <p><!-- Tab content here --></p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content2 -->
    <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
     <h3>Grow the Movement</h3>
        <p><!-- Tab content here --></p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content2 -->
```

CSS

```
.tabs {
    max-width: 90%;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 75px auto;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
}
.tabs:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
}
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #ccc;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tabs label span {
    display: none;
}
.tabs label i {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.tabs label:hover {
    color: #3498db;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #3498db;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3498db;
}
.tab-content {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.tab-content * {
    -webkit-animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
    animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.01);
    opacity: 0.5;
    }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #3498db;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3498db;
    color: #3498db;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #tab-content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #tab-content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #tab-content3 {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .tabs i {
        padding: 5px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .tabs label span {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .tabs {
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    }
}
```

Thank you kindly,
Andy

Comment: The key will be winning the war of specificity.  Consider adding an ID attribute to your outermost tabs container element, then adding a CSS selector that targets the ID prior to the class (i.e. `#snazzy-tabs.tabs` and so on).  Also, ideally your stylesheet will appear in the page after the existing styles.  Following that, if there are still issues check out the style rules applied to tab-related elements in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: thank you, i'll give that a try

Comment: @SimianAngel i notice your #snazzy-tabs.tabs does't have a space before the .tabs, while some other examples i found while reading further from your comment do. is that a typing error, or there a reason?

Comment: That was purposeful.  `#snazzy-tabs.tabs` is a more specific selector; it selects an element with an `id` attribute of "snazzy-tabs" **and** with a `class` attribute that includes "tabs".  The idea is that when you add an ID to a specific set of tabs on the page, that element (and it's descendents) still benefit from the cascade and inherit the styles of all tabs.  However, you can override those styles as needed by selecting both the ID and the tabs class, replacing only the rules and properties that you want to display differently. CSS rules with the greatest specificity win. :)

Comment: thanks, that's excellent to know for the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In add to the common solution of targeting the element itself, and then the class, AKA: '.paragraph' vs 'p.paragraph', you can also force some !important rules... wich can make your code a little spaghetti for further development, since you'd have to pin down more styles.... I can tell, maybe it's good making a second .css file just to store those !important rules, so it's easier to find.

The implementation is like as follows:

```
p.pragraph {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  letter-spacing 1px !important;
}
```

basically, through each style change, add the "!important" before the ";".

Comment: thanks for the answer. this wouldn't work though as i need both sets of css to run on different elements of the same page, so i can't overwrite one set of rules.

Comment: In adding to that, you can specify new classes for elements to help targeting them, and pinpoint everything. In addition, a nice tool to use on google chrome is to open developers console (f12), then browse to the element you can target, right click it on the code, go to COPY tab and choose the option: COPY SELECTOR... that will bring you to the closest single element targeting you can by using cascading on your style sheets, or by targetting element unique ID

Comment: If it is not helpful, I'm very sorry to misinterpret your comment.